# WinForms: DataGridView - Show Combobox when cell being Edit

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, datagridtextcolumn

In a C# app, I have a DatagridView with all cells as DataGridTextBoxCol. Grid is populated dynamically with unbound values. Grid has different type of food items.
   My need is, when user clicks/wants to edit a cell - a combo box with list of food items appears in place of cell. If their is any value in cell, then that value should be selected in combo. User can type and item gets selected in combo.
   This is what I have tried so far:

```
private void PopulateAllergensCombo()
    {
        // Populate Combo box in Form_load & be hidden
        BindingSource allergensBindSource = new BindingSource();
        allergensList = dbOperations.GetAllergensListObjects();

        allergensBindSource.DataSource = allergensList;

        allergensCmb.DataSource = allergensBindSource.DataSource;   // allergensList;
        allergensCmb.DisplayMember = "Name";
        allergensCmb.ValueMember = "AllergensNumber";
    }
```

To place this combo `allergensCmb`in the current cell

```
        private void cellAssignments_dgv_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCell dvCell = cellAssignments_dgv.CurrentCell;

        allergensCmb.Location = dvCell.ContentBounds.Location; // location of cell is X=0, Y=11 - This seems to be relevant from grid & not from Form

        if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty(cellAssignments_dgv.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()) == false )
            allergensCmb.SelectedValue = cellAssignments_dgv.CurrentCell.Value;
        allergensCmb.Show();
    }
```

As with the above `dgv_CellBeginEdit`event code, the combo doesn't show in the cell location. Location of the cell is X=0, Y=11 - 1st col 1st row cell. It's not relevant to the form dimensions.
To get and set the value of item selected from combo in the grid cell, I tried implementing CellEndEdit and allergensCmb_SelectedIndexChanged events. But nothing works full 100%. With selectedIndexChanged event, I have lost the current cell as cell is no more active; can't get the current cell or if it is dirty!!

Any clue, how do I implement this type of control - show a Combobox on the current cell of the DataGridView. I did lots of research and tried out, but nothing works as expected.

Any help is highly appreciated.

//////////////////////////////////////////
************ UPDATIONS
//////////////////////////////////////////

As you both suggested to use DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, I did:

```
// Add Columns
        for (int i = 1; i <= pair.Value.CellBodyRowData.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            cbCol.HeaderText = i.ToString();
            cbCol.Name = i.ToString();

            cbCol.DataSource = allergensList;
            cbCol.ValueMember = "AllergensNumber";
            cbCol.DisplayMember = "Name";

            cellAssignments_dgv.Columns.Add(cbCol);

            // *** cellAssignments_dgv.Columns.Add((i.ToString(), i.ToString());
        }

// Populate in each Row
foreach (CellBodyRowData cbrData in cbRow.CellBodyRowData)
                {
                    // *****  dgvr.Cells[cbrData.Col - 1].Value = cbrData.CellAllergen.Name;

                    if (cbrData.CellAllergen.AllergensNumber > 0)
                        dgvr.Cells[cbrData.Col - 1].Value = cbrData.CellAllergen.AllergensNumber;
                    else
                        dgvr.Cells[cbrData.Col - 1].Value = 0;

                }
```

This is fine. In grid, I see each cell as ComboBox only. How do I make it show as normal text only and only while editing it appears as a combobox. And what is the reason to use EditingControlShowing event - I don't get that logic ?? I jut need to change the value & set a flag `isCellAssignGridChanged` to true, so can update the DB.

Can you please throw some light on this part.

Thanks

Comment: Rather than shuffling between a CBO and the DGV, you could add a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to the grid

Comment: Have you tried the editcontrolshowing event?

Comment: @Plutonix, the grid may have several of cells & all have food items name only. So many CMB with same list/data makes it too heavy. Hence this way.

Comment: @JohnKane, No, I didn't look at that event. Checking for the same.

Comment: If it is the same list, use the same DataSource and no extra overhead at all.

Comment: @Plutonix, yes list will be the same. But the selected item will be different in most cells. Won't that yet affect the performance compared to textcell !

Comment: @JohnKane, here on TextCell I want to show a different Combobox. EditControlShowing event _Occurs when a control for editing a cell is showing_ - this is not relevant to my needs.

Comment: Make it a combobox rather than a text cell...u can default certain properties to make it look like a text box...then editcontrolshowing will work

Comment: @JohnKane, I made my Cols as ComboBoxCols & set the value on populating the grid. The Grid cells are shown as ComboBox only - how do I show it just as Text ??

Comment: Dropdownstyle to none?

Comment: @JohnKane, Yes got to hide & show DropDown ->  cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;  The CellEndEdit is not being called until I select another cell. I added SelectionChangeCommitted to cb, call cellAssignments_dgv.EndEdit();. It's calling, but SelectionChangeCommitted  is being fired on any text also I write. For eg. in the list I have Mayo, Milk, Mint,  I type M - it selects Mayo & fire. I type "Mi" -> Firres, type "Mil" -> Fires & selects Milk. Any way to fire CellEndEdit only once any where user clicks in or out of grid ???

Comment: Once user has selected an item, I just want to call code to update the collection object and set a flag indicating that Grid has been changed. Code for this is written in CellEndEdit. If same can be accomplished by something else, I have no issue. Please suggest, b'coz I don't wish to call code to update collection so many times & for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Plutonix and @JohnKane.

1. I changed the cols to `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` in the grid.
2. Change the `DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;` of the cols.
3. Implemented `EditingControlShowing` event and changed the dropdown style   `cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;`& SelectionChangeCommitted for the Combobox

   ```
   private void cellAssignments_dgv_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Control is ComboBox)
       {
           ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)e.Control;
           if (cb != null)
           {
               // Show the DropDown of the combo & set its event
               cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

               cb.SelectionChangeCommitted -= cb_SelectionChangeCommitted;
               cb.SelectionChangeCommitted += cb_SelectionChangeCommitted;
           }
       }
   }

   void cb_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;

       if (cb != null)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Selected Combo = " + cb.SelectedText + " Value = " + cb.SelectedValue);

           // Notify the cell is dirty
           cellAssignments_dgv.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
           // Force to End Edit the Cell
           cellAssignments_dgv.EndEdit();
       }

   }
   ```
4. Finally, in `CellEndEdit` event, implemented my update update the collection object

Hope this helps some one.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for publishing your answer. I am surprised there is no easier way suggested!